# UML - use case diagrams

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

I'm creating a chat application based on web services. I want to draw a use case diagram for my application. My problem is when i'm drawing the use case diagram should i indicate web service ? if i want how to indicate that?

Answer (score 1):

You show it as a boundary enclosing the use cases. The actors are outside. It's a common use to put primary actors to the left of the boundary and secondary ones to the right.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But i want to know that should i show the  web service as an actor or as a use case ?